# What is difference between var name: String? and var name: String

Tags: kotlin

I'm new to Kotlin Programming lang.
I've been developing apps in android.
I found a data class taking constructor with `String?` and `String`
Can anyone make me understand this.

```
data class Person(var name: String?) {
//... 
}
data class Person(var name: String) {
//...
}
```

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`String?` can be null and `String` can not be null, that's about all there's to it.

Answer (score 8):

When you use `?`, it tells, you can have null value also. Because Kotlin enforces [null safety](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html).

See comments in following code:

```
data class Person(var name: String?) { // This can have null value also
//...
}
data class Person(var name: String) { // This can not have a null value, it will give compile time error.
//...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The "?" operator defines the null-ability of a variable.

Examples:

Accept String type but also accept null value.

```
var x :String? = ""
x = null // works fine
```

Only accept String type, in case you intent to set it's value to null will provoke a compilation error.

```
var x :String = ""
x = null // will provoke a compilation error.
```

It's important to keep in mind after you check the null value of a variable it will be automatically cast to non-nullable type.

```
fun test() {

    var x: String? = ""
    x = null // works fine
    x = "String type" // works fine

    if(x == null) {
      println("The var x can't be null")
      return
    }

    x = null // will provoke a compilation error.
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {

   test()
}
```

[Kotlin Documentation, null-safety](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html)

Comment: This is somewhat misleading, please edit.  The `?` operator is not the null safety operator, it is the nullability of a type.  Plus your examples do not use that operator after you say "example:" ... lastly the last comment isn't always true, especially for a var unless it is a local variable that could never be modified by another thread.

Comment: I edited my answer and added the suggestions commented by @JaysonMinard

Answer (score 0):

A variable declared with **?** indicates that the variable **may or may not** be null.

Otherwise, it is interpreted as a non-null value.

Such a feature was explicitly added to Kotlin to reduce/prevent a common runtime error, **NullPointerException**.

For eg:

```
var a: String? = "abc"
a.length        // Compile Time Error, trying to access possibly null value

var b: String = "xyz"
b.length        // No Error, the value is never null
```

Having said that, you can assert that a value is not null using `!!` which will remove the compiler error, but add the risk of a NPE:

```
var a: String? = "abc"
a!!.length        // Will cause Run Time Exception if a is null
```

Comment: Also in the example above, doing an a?.length is a null-safe way of checking the length where it returns a null if a is null and the actual length if a is not null.

Answer (score -3):

The `?` would be for safe casting operator for **kotlin**. 
For eg. if we have a cast operation like :

```
val x: String = y as String
```

and if `y` is `null`, then the above code will throw an exception. To avoid this, we can use safe cast operator (`?`). The above snippet becomes :

```
val x: String? = y as? String
```

This will return `null` if there is any kind of failure while casting.
Please find the reading at this [link](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/typecasts.html)

Comment: ? is not a safe casting operator in Kotlin; the safe casting operator is "as?". Moreover, in this example there are no casts; the example declares a property of a nullable type.